# Oracle Trigger Parallel Execution

Tags: oracle, plsql

let's assume (for theoretical reasons) that there is an after update row level trigger which calls a procedure of a package which runs a long time, 5 minutes.
Is there any way this trigger might be executed a second time while the 1st execution still runs?

What would happen if you trigger the trigger from session A once and then immediately again?

What would happen if you trigger the trigger from session A once and the immdeiately from session B again?

Would they run in parallel or just wait 5 mins before the 1st run is finished?

Would it make any difference if we talk about row level triggers or statement level trigger when it comes to these questions?

Thanks.

Comment: You could (theoretically) push jobs into a queue within the trigger(s) to resolve a great many long-running execution concerns, (theoretically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly easy to test, e.g. by displaying the start and end time in the procedure. (Sample code to demonstrate is below). Within session A, if you do:

```
update <table> set ...;
update <table> set ...;
```

... the trigger will fire for each affected row, in series, for the first update as part of that statement; and then it will execute the second update, the trigger will fire for each affected row, in series again. The procedure will only be running once at any time, however may updates you do and however many rows are affected by each one.

Changing to a statement-level trigger would still only have the procedure running once at any time, but it would run fewer times overall if the updates affect more than one row - once per update, rather than once per updated row.

But if you run the second update from session B simultaneously (and it's touching different rows in the table), it would not be affected by the first session, and then you *will* have the procedure running twice at the same time. It doesn't matter if that's a row-level or statement-level trigger; it'll be running once in each session.

If you wanted to avoid the procedure running twice from different sessions you'd need to implement some kind of locking mechanism, e.g. updating a control flag in another table at the start of the procedure. That would be released when that session commits or rolls back, and the other session will then continue and obtain its own lock.

Having a trigger that calls a procedure that takes that long seems very wrong though. It sounds like you have business and application logic in the wrong place...

---

Demo code, for running twice in session A:

```
create table t42 (id number);

insert into t42 values (1);
insert into t42 values (2);

create package p42 as
  procedure busy;
end p42;
/

create package body p42 as
  procedure busy is
    x number;
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Started  ' || systimestamp);
    for i in 1..200000 loop -- takes about 4s on my system
      select 1 into x from dual;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('Finished ' || systimestamp);
  end busy;
end p42;
/

create trigger trig42
after update on t42
for each row
begin
  p42.busy;
end;
/
```

Then run two updates:

```
update t42 set id = id + 1;
update t42 set id = id + 1;
```

Gets output:

```
2 rows updated.
Started  08-AUG-13 18.17.49.184770000 +01:00
Finished 08-AUG-13 18.17.53.041916000 +01:00
Started  08-AUG-13 18.17.53.042109000 +01:00
Finished 08-AUG-13 18.17.56.841698000 +01:00

2 rows updated.
Started  08-AUG-13 18.17.57.027777000 +01:00
Finished 08-AUG-13 18.18.01.172613000 +01:00
Started  08-AUG-13 18.18.01.172730000 +01:00
Finished 08-AUG-13 18.18.04.963734000 +01:00
```

The procedure runs four times in total, and timestamps show the procedure execution is serial. If we run ID-specific updates in session A and session B simultaneously, session A sees this:

```
update t42 set id = id + 1 where id = 1;
1 rows updated.
Started  08-AUG-13 18.21.09.098922000 +01:00
Finished 08-AUG-13 18.21.16.355744000 +01:00
```

and session B sees this:

```
update t42 set id = id + 1 where id = 2;
Started  08-AUG-13 18.21.09.500643000 +01:00
Finished 08-AUG-13 18.21.16.204506000 +01:00
1 row updated.
```

As you can see, the timestamps overlap, so the procedure is running twice concurrently.

Adding a very simple locking mechanism:

```
create table t43 (id number);
insert into t43 values(null);

create package body p42 as
  procedure busy is
    x number;
  begin
    update t43 set id = 1;
    dbms_output.put_line('Started  ' || systimestamp);
  ...
end p42;
```

Then in session A:

```
update t42 set id = id + 1 where id = 1;
1 rows updated.
Started  08-AUG-13 18.22.35.058741000 +01:00
Finished 08-AUG-13 18.22.39.288557000 +01:00
rollback;
```

And simultaneously in session B:

```
update t42 set id = id + 1 where id = 2;
Started  08-AUG-13 18.22.40.385602000 +01:00
Finished 08-AUG-13 18.22.43.995601000 +01:00
1 row updated.
rollback;
```

Now the calls from the two sessions are serialised too. The session B update's procedure call can't start until session A has rolled back, so if session A did multiple actions it could block for longer.

Comment: Thank you, very comprehensive example

Answer (score 3):

Triggers execute  as soon as the condition occurs - thus, if triggered twice in session A the trigger would run once for the first occurrence, then run again for the second occurrence, and thus the executions would be performed serially and would take a total of 10 minutes. If the trigger is fired once from session A and then immediately fired from session B the two occurrences would run concurrently. A statement trigger will only be fired once per statement, rather than once for each row (which is kind of the whole point of having statement vs. row triggers). And BTW - 5 minutes is TOO LONG for a trigger to run - triggers need to be fired, get their work done, and get the h*ll out of the way. If you've got something that takes five minutes which needs to be run then create a table, use the trigger to insert data into the table which describes/defines what needs to be processed, and get out of the trigger.  You'd need to have a program which pulls data out of the table and processes it appropriately - but IMO under NO circumstances should a trigger be allowed to run for five minutes.

YMMV.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

1. From one session you can trigger only one action at a time, isn't it? There is no multithreading unless it is a background job. So first question scenario is not possible.
2. Both will execute concurrently
3. If second trigger is from different session then parallel else sequentially.
4. Above points will apply to all scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to all of the questions - the triggers are always executed immediately, there's no reason for them to be synchronised at all. In fact, that would be a huge problem for highly concurrent systems. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/server.1111/e25789/consist.htm) how Oracle RDBMS manages concurrency.

BTW, there's another significant challenge with a heavy reliance on triggers: the [mutating error](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936)